# GET 404() error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

как исправить такие ошибки в WordPress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Такие ошибки говорят о том, что по указанному пути нет запрашиваемых файлов (например, по ссылке http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js нет файла html5.js). Проверьте правильность пути и исправьте его, либо положите файлы в те директории, к которым идёт обращение.